# ¿Cómo imprimir varias fechas y mostrar un solo mes con todos sus días?

Tags: php, mysql

Resulta que en mi base de datos tengo varias fechas, con su respectiva clave en este caso la clave `X` tiene esta fecha y todo va bien, cuando las logro imprimir me muestra lo siguiente:

```
clv_b   fechas_bloque  type  

1206  &nbsp;  2017-03-23  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
1206  &nbsp;  2017-03-21  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
1206  &nbsp;  2017-03-26  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
1206  &nbsp;  2017-05-11  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
1206  &nbsp;  2017-05-26  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
1206  &nbsp;  2017-06-04  &nbsp;&nbsp;   1<br>
```

Con el siguiente código traigo todas las fechas que están activas que son de tipo `1`.

```
$SQL_bloqueos_fecha = "SELECT * FROM Bloqueos where clv_b= ".$CLV." ORDER BY 
fechas_bloque ASC";

$rs = $db->Execute($SQL_bloqueos_fecha) or die("Error: $SQL_bloqueos_fecha. 
<br />" . $db->ErrorMsg());

    while (!$rs->EOF) {
    $type = $rs->fields['type'];
    $bloque_fecha = $rs->fields['fechas_bloque'];
    if ($type  == 1) {

     setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
     $fecha = strftime(' %B, %d ',strtotime($bloque_fecha));
     echo "$fecha<br>";
    }   
    $rs->MoveNext();}
```

Con esto

```
if ($type  == 1) {

     setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
     $fecha = strftime(' %B, %d ',strtotime($bloque_fecha));
     echo "$fecha<br>";
    }
```

los convierto para que queden de esta forma, hasta aquí todo bien

```
marzo, 23, 2017
marzo, 21, 2017
marzo, 26, 2017
mayo, 11, 2017
mayo, 26, 2017
junio, 04, 2017
```

Lo que quiero es que queden de esta forma, espero me de a entender.

```
marzo, 23,21,26
mayo, 11,26
junio, 04
```

Comment: Ya entendí. Por favor agrega la consulta con la que obtienes los datos, por ahí debes empezar. Consulta la guía [mcve] al editar tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar si alguna de las respuestas resuelven tu problema o si necesitas alguna aclaración de ellas? Por favor, marca como respuesta correcta la que solucione tu problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Yo cambiaría la consulta SQL por la siguiente:

```
$SQL_bloqueos_fecha = "
  SELECT
    fechas_bloque,
    GROUP_CONCAT(dia) dias
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(LEFT(fechas_bloque, 7), '-01') fechas_bloque,
      RIGHT(fechas_bloque, 2) dia
    FROM
      Bloqueos
    WHERE
      clv_b = 1
  ) sub
  GROUP BY
    fechas_bloque
  ORDER BY
    fechas_bloque ASC;
";
```

Primero hago una consulta en la que convierto todas las fechas al día 1 del mes (para su posterior agrupación) y separo el día en un campo a parte con las funciones de cadenas [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) y [`RIGHT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_right).

Luego realizo un agrupamiento por fecha y hago uso de [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) para obtener todos los valores agregados separados por comas (por defecto).

Tendrás dos campos: `fechas_bloque` (para pasar a `strtotime` apuntando siempre al día 1) y `dias` (con el listado de días dentro de un mes).

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo en línea.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xB4dvKGx1ixD6FMURrDDco/0)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que haría sería guardar las fechas en un array.

Luego, recorro dicho array para generar variables con nombre del mes. Con una variable de control también recorro el array y agrego un único valor de mes al tiempo que agrego en la variable de nombre del mes los días. Luego imprimo.

Seguro que se puede simplificar. Creo que no es necesario el control.

```
    $array = [
"marzo, 23, 2017",
"marzo, 21, 2017",
"marzo, 26, 2017",
"mayo, 11, 2017",
"mayo, 26, 2017",
"junio, 04, 2017"
];

$control=[];

foreach($array as $a){
$b=explode(',',$a);
$$b[0]='';
}

foreach($array as $a){

$b = explode(',',$a);

if(!in_array($b[0],$control)){

        array_push($control,$b[0]);
        $$b[0].= $b[1].',' ;
}else{
        $$b[0].=$b[1].',';
}
}
foreach($control as $c){
echo $c.' '.$$c;
}
```

Comment: Tu wihile debería dar como resultado un array y, a partir de allí, utilizar el script que te pasé, fuera del while.